# Rotate SCNNode to where user taps

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I want the bobNode to look at the location the user taps on the screen. I am struggling to rotate the bobNode. I am logging the tap location and it works when I tap. I never get the `print("Angle: " + String(describing: angle))`. The only time `print("Testing Renderer function")` is when the app loads, it prints 11 times and no more after that. I guess im jsut confused on the concept of rotating the bobNode. If I am going about it wrong can someone explain to me on how to go about this.

Code:

```
var sceneView: SCNView! // for now
var bobNode: SCNNode!
var lastTouch: CGPoint? = nil

let bobScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/man.scn")!

func start(){
    let scene = SCNScene()

    sceneView.delegate = self

    bobNode = bobScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Player", recursively: true)!

    bobNode.scale = SCNVector3(x: 0.15, y: 0.15, z: 0.15)
    bobNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(x: GLKMathDegreesToRadians(75), y: 0.0, z: GLKMathDegreesToRadians(180))//Don't use rotaion THAT shit is retarded

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(bobNode)

    sceneView.scene = scene

    let camera = SCNCamera()
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = camera
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: bobNode.position.x, y: bobNode.position.y, z: 10.0)

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)        

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    handleTouches(touches: touches)
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    handleTouches(touches: touches)
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    handleTouches(touches: touches)
}

private func handleTouches(touches: Set<UITouch>) {
    for touch in touches {
        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: sceneView)
        lastTouch = touchLocation
        print("Touch: " + String(describing: lastTouch))
    }
}

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didSimulatePhysicsAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
    if let _ = bobNode {
        updatePlayer()
    }
}

func updatePlayer() {
    print("Testing Renderer function")
    if let touch = lastTouch {
        let currentPosition = bobNode.position

        let angle = atan2(CGFloat(currentPosition.y) - CGFloat(touch.y), CGFloat(currentPosition.x) - CGFloat(touch.x)) + CGFloat(Double.pi)

        print("Angle: " + String(describing: angle))

        let rotateAction = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0.0, y: angle, z: 0.0, duration: 0)

        bobNode.runAction(rotateAction)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to add an **SCNLookAtConstraint** to `bobNode`.

When you create an SCNLookAtConstraint it requires a **target SCNNode** and SceneKit will rotate `bobNode` towards the given target at each frame.

Let's call it `targetNode` (presumably with no geometry) that is in the scene 3D space right under the location the user taps. Its position will need to be updated as the user taps change.

Of course, user taps are represented as a 2D point in the screen's coordinate space and it will need to be translated to the scene's 3D space.

This can be done with your **SCNView's** `unprojectPoint:` method.
You have to pass it an SCNVector3 parameter, which holds the X and Y coordinates of the screen tap, and it's Z component is between 0.0 and 1.0 and represents the depth at which the 2D point to be projected in the scene 3D space (between near and far clipping planes of the camera). I guess you need it close to 0.0 here.

Setup

```
// Create the look-at constraint
SCNLookAtConstraint lookAtConstr = [SCNLookAtConstraint lookAtConstraintWithTarget:];

// Set to bobNode's .constraints property
bobNode.constraints = @[lookAtConstr];
```

At each frame

```
// tapLocation is the screen tap location from UIEvent
SCNVector3 tapPosition = SCNVector3Make(tapLocation.x, tapLocation.y, 0.0);

// unproject from 2D screen to 3D scene space
SCNVector3 targetNodePosition = [scnView unprojectPoint:tapPosition];

// Update the targetNode position
targetNode.position = targetNodePosition;
```